# Why R bootstrap function uses indices to calculate mean ratio?

Tags: r, function, indexing, mean, statistics-bootstrap

I am looking to use bootstrapping for a mean of a sample that I have. I have been researching bootstrap package applications in R and I found something that is very confusing to me. On CRAN this is official example given for bootstrap function:

```
# Usual bootstrap of the ratio of means using the city data
ratio <- function(d, w) sum(d$x * w)/sum(d$u * w)
boot(city, ratio, R = 999, stype = "w")
```

it is using city data in R

Why in the function it is calculating sum of x TIMES the index? It doesn't give a value of mean ratio.

Comment: Since `stype = "w"` is set, the `boot()` function is passing weights to the `statistics` function as the second parameter, not the index. So `w` are weights and and the `ratio` function is calculating a weighted ratio of means.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you! but how do I prevent that? in my application I have two samples and I want to see if their means are the same. So what I was planning to do is to get all the means for sample A - get confidence interval , and same for sample B. However the weights it is assigning are not equal - they are related to the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have an example like, this and the samples are independent,

```
library(boot)
set.seed(100)
x=rpois(100,3)
y=rpois(100,5)
```

You just add something more to the mean function to do bootstrap:

```
boot_x = boot(x,function(i,d)mean(i[d]),R=999)
boot.ci(boot_x,type="perc")
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 999 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_x, type = "perc")

Intervals : 
Level     Percentile     
95%   ( 2.79,  3.39 )  

boot_y = boot(y,function(i,d)mean(i[d]),R=999)
```

### and so on...

If the observations are paired, and you are interested in the difference, you should have them in a data.frame, and do:

```
x=rpois(100,3)
y= x+ rnorm(100,2,1)
df = data.frame(x,y)
boot_df = boot(df,function(i,d)mean(i[d,1] - i[d,2]),R=999)
```